# Как вращать прямоугольник вокруг своей оси во время его движения?

Tags: svg

```
 <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1500" height="1500">
 
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="10" height="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
        <animate attributeName="x" to="500" dur="2s" repeatCount="indefinite"/>
    </rect>
        
</svg>
```

с помощью `<animateTransform>` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше использовать для перемещения команду трансформации `translate()` она менее ресурсно затратная по сравнению с изменением координаты `x`

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1500" height="1500">
    <polyline stroke="silver" points="105,110 600,110" />
     <g id="rectMove"> 
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="10" height="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
           <!-- Вращение прямоугольника      -->
     <animateTransform id="an_rot" " attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="0.8s"
      values="0 105 110;360 105 110" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
    </rect>  
            <!-- Перемещение прямоугольника -->
      <animateTransform id="an_tr"  attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s" dur="12s"
      values="10;500" repeatCount="1" />      
    </g>
       
</svg>
```

**Пример с повторным вращением с паузой 1s в конце анимации**

`begin="0s;an_tr.end+1s"`

```html
<svg xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
 width="1500" height="1500">
    <polyline stroke="silver" points="105,120 600,120" />
     <g id="rectMove"> 
    <rect x="100" y="100" width="10" height="20" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="none">
           <!-- Вращение прямоугольника      -->
     <animateTransform id="an_rot" " attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="0s" dur="0.8s"
      values="0 105 110;360 105 110" repeatCount="indefinite" />  
    </rect>  
            <!-- Перемещение прямоугольника -->
      <animateTransform id="an_tr"  attributeName="transform" type="translate" begin="0s;an_tr.end+1s" dur="12s"
      values="10;500" repeatCount="1" />      
    </g>
       
</svg>
```